# Measuring effects of categorical factors on binomial outcome with many groups

Tags: r, regression, anova, binomial-distribution, multilevel-analysis

I'd like to do some analysis of shooting efficiency in basketball when a team is leading (AHEAD) or trailing (BEHIND) by less than 8 points and whether they are HOME or AWAY. Here are a few examples of the data:

```
Ray Allen   HOME    BEHIND  59.4%   134
Ray Allen   HOME    AHEAD   57.13%  132
Ray Allen   AWAY    BEHIND  49.1%   166
Ray Allen   AWAY    AHEAD   48.03%  126
Jason Terry AWAY    BEHIND  56.6%   242
Jason Terry HOME    BEHIND  52.0%   193
Jason Terry AWAY    AHEAD   50.05%  198
Jason Terry HOME    AHEAD   48.73%  207
Jamal Crawford  AWAY    AHEAD   51.65%  82
Jamal Crawford  HOME    AHEAD   42.50%  178
Jamal Crawford  AWAY    BEHIND  35.5%   129
Jamal Crawford  HOME    BEHIND  33.4%   118
Kevin Durant    HOME    BEHIND  48.6%   222
Kevin Durant    HOME    AHEAD   44.05%  248
Kevin Durant    AWAY    BEHIND  41.4%   325
Kevin Durant    AWAY    AHEAD   40.07%  213
```

The 4th column is the FG% (i.e. proportion of made shots) and the 5th column is the number of shots (i.e. trials).

You can see even with these 4 players (and there are roughly 200 in the data set), that there is variation of the mean FG% between players, and for each player, there is not a consistent pattern in whether they are "better" at HOME or AWAY or AHEAD or BEHIND. So there's a lot of variance between groups and within groups as far as I can tell.

I thought about using lmer, but I wasn't sure how to do that for this problem, because if I just use the FG% as the outcome, I lose the information about how many shots were taken. Eventually, I'd like to put this into BUGS, but I thought there might be a more straightforward way for now, because I'm not quite ready for that yet.

I should just add that what I'm really after is a way to determine whether a player is "really" better under one of these conditions, or are the apparent differences just due to noise/variation from small sample sizes.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: This question seems to call for a **binomial model**. E.g., putting the data in a data.frame with variables Name, Home, Ahead, Percent, and N, to get started (with a simple linear model, no interactions) you would account for the number of shot attempts by executing `data$K <- floor(data$Percent * data$N / 100 + 0.5);
data$L <- data$N - data$K;
fit <- glm(cbind(K,L) ~ Name + Home + Ahead, data=data, family=binomial());
summary(fit)`.  Is there some reason you haven't done this?

Comment: @whuber, I didn't know you could put the response in that form. Let me see if this works. I would also like to have interaction terms.

Comment: Put interactions in in the usual way. But start out without them to get a baseline.

Comment: Well, I just ran this model w/o interactions, and it came back with only 3 players having a p-val<0.05. This doesn't really help me.

Comment: How not, Evan? That sounds like a useful result to me. It's telling you there are few detectable differences among players after you factor in the other variables. However, such a result might not be credible in light of obvious differences in basketball performance. In fact, I found significant player differences even in the small subset you posted. It sounds like you should experiment on a smaller dataset and make sure you're applying and interpreting the procedures correctly by exploring the data extensively and producing diagnostics for the procedures.

Answer (score 1):

To circumvent the 200-players problem, you could fit whichever model you choose (logit, binomial...), without the player variable as such, but inside a [discrete mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model) framework. You'll have to process the data right (for instance you want to make sure that all stats of a single player are taken together, and you'll have to determine the optimal number of clusters in the mixture) but the fitted mixture model will group players into clusters, which should reflect differences in performance, or rather differences in how the conditions (home and ahead) affect performance. This is very easy and fast with R package flexmix.

Building on the same idea, you could also just run an unsupervized clustering algo (k-means, gaussian mixture, self-organizing map) on the data transformed as such: each player has one vector of 8 values $(rate_{home,lead}, N_{home, lead}, rate_{home, behind}, N_{home, behind}, ...)$. In that case each player belongs to a cluster of players with similar characteristics, and you can check whether the differences between clusters are significant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could fit a logistic regression model using player, ahead/behind, home/away, percentage success and number of shots taken under those conditions as possible covariates.  Then difficulty with player is that you have over 200.  I think that success percentage under specific conditions could serve as a substitute for player since the player and his past performance under the conditions should be highly related to the outcome.  To predict for individual players you just use that player's other covariates.

Comment: Does that work even for factors with hundreds of levels like the player factor here? Also, the 5th column (number of shots) is really just acting as the number of trials. It's not something I would want to fit, but I think it should be taken into account for the sample size that the FG% is based on. Does that make sense?

Comment: How many players do you have data on?

Comment: The player and his field goal percentages should be highly correlated.  It may be just as good to drop player and just use the remaining 4 covariates.

Comment: @Michael, clearly different players have different "baselines" e.g. Shaq would have a much higher baseline than Jason Kidd in terms of FG %. Averaging over those (which is effectively what happens when you only use the 4 remaining variables) may be hard to interpret, wouldn't you say? Why not use a random intercept for each player?

Comment: There are around 200 players. The thing is what I'm most interested in *is* the player.

Comment: Logistic? Where is the binary response?

Comment: @whuber, the FG % can be readily converted to # of successes, and you have number of trials in the last column, making this a usual binomial regression situation (of course, if you've assumed that trials are independent).

Comment: @Macro Are you suggesting regressing the logit of the FG% against the other variables? I hope that at least you use the number of attempts as an offset--and at that point, how would this approach be superior to the binomial GLM?

Comment: @whuber, that's not necessarily a bad idea but that wasn't what I was suggesting. I'm suggesting treating the number of FGs made as a binomial outcome with a known number of trials (given by the last column) - this then becomes to usual binomial GLM, perhaps with random effects if the individual player is treated as a random effect, which, I think, could make sense.

Comment: @Macro OK, I get you now. I would think your approach should be very close to a binomial model with log link, if not identical. But I don't understand why you would use random player effects when the interest is focused on the individual players.

Comment: @whuber, I think that some information about the players could be gleaned from a random intercept. At least you could see whether there is a lot of heterogeneity in the baselines and you could look at posterior random effect estimates. Also, I don't think including 200 fixed effects (the OP says there are 200 players) is practical, unless you had something else in mind.

Comment: Good points, @Macro. It depends partly on the purpose: the binomial (or logit) GLM is basically serving as a way to analyze a multiway contingency table. If the purpose is primarily to analyze that as a *description* of one season of basketball, then 200 fixed effects do a good job of describing performance after home/away and ahead/behind have been "factored in." But inference is a different issue and that's where your point about so many fixed effects becomes relevant: that's a lot of comparisons to make and few, if any, would be significant.

Comment: *Inference* is definitely what I'm after here. Anyone can calculate means, and that's usually all that is done. Say, Player A shoots 51% and Player B shoots 49%, you will always see a sports commentator saying Player A > Player B. But given the amount of variation and noise, who really knows if Player A > Player B next year? That's what I want to know. What can inferences/predictions can I really make about these data?

Comment: @Macro's point, Evan (if I interpret it correctly), is that with so many players you're going to get a wide spread of results and *of course* some will be at either extreme just by chance alone. It could be invalid to infer that those players are significantly better or worse. One way to go further is to include multiple years of data and check for consistency of performance from one year to the next. Elementary calculations tell us that we *ought* to see $\pm 10$% spreads in performance--due solely to chance--when breaking it down into groups of around $100$ attempts.

Comment: I do have multiple years of data, but I pooled them together. Shouldn't that be equivalent with binomial data? Let me put it another way, if a player shoots 50/100 4 years in a row, does that tell us more than if he shot 200/400 in 4 years?

Comment: @EvanZ Each additional outcome tells you something because the factors home/away, ahead/behind and any others will vary.

Comment: @Macro I think that the OP is using different FG percentages for the player based on the other covariates.  So given four percentages i think that roughly characterizes the player.

Comment: Let me give another clear example of why I think I may need a multi-level model (or a full Bayesian approach). Rasual Butler is not a very good basketball player (he might not even be in the league anymore). Continuing...

Comment: Anyway, in 28 shots when on the road and his team up by 0-8 points, Butler shot a gaudy 85.7%. The confidence interval for this (from qbinom) is 71.4% to 96.4% (2.5%-ile,97.5%-ile). Nobody on earth believes Rasual Butler would shoot in that range if he had 100 or 200 or 300 attempts. It's just a random fluke given that there are hundreds of players being studied. My thought is that the multi-level model (as described in Gelman's 2007 book) would help regress his % to the mean. I'm just not exactly sure how to do this when there are multiple factors and so many groups.

Comment: Butler's percentage is a highly variable estimate because he only took 28 shots.  So percentage by itself is not a good covariate but taken together percentage and number of shots may be useful.  I think if another player took 28 shots and hit on 85.7% we would want to treat him the same way as Butler.  So I do not see where the full specification of every player is necessary.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I'm not sure how much you follow basketball, but if you did, you would know that 85.7% is absolutely much higher than his "real" shooting percentage. The average shooting % in the NBA is around 50%. We need to take into account the other players because that's our frame of reference. It's like in baseball, a batter could hit 0.500 in 28 at-bats, but nobody has ever come close (to my knowledge) to being a 0.500 batter in 280 at-bats.

Comment: I know a lot about basketball.  I think the avergae FG percentage is below 50% even the a good foul shot percentage is below 80%.  My point is that 85% with 28 tries is very different from 85% with 200 tries and that is taken into account by the combination of the two covariates.

Comment: How so? Sorry, but it's not clear to me what exactly you're suggesting I should do. I realize that I can do a regression pooling all the players and using cbind(n,y) as the outcome, but then I wouldn't have any information about the players themselves. Like I said, what I really want to know is whether the players shoot better or worse under certain conditions (and compared to each other).

Comment: I don't need to go to chat on this.  All I am saying is that FG %age under the 4 different conditions provides specific player information that is may not be totally unique does separate the players without having to specify each player's individual performance.  I just don't see the random intercept or the 200 individual players as hacking it as approaches.

Comment: @MichaelChernick So is your suggestion to do glm(fg% ~ HOME + AHEAD + #shots, family=binomial()) or glm(cbind(#makes,#shots) ~ HOME + AHEAD,family=binomial())? Or something else? I'm not trying to be argumentative, but it's not clear to me (still) what you think I should actually be executing in R.

Comment: Yes a logistic (i.e. generalized linear model with the logit link) regression with all the covariates except for player.

Comment: @EvanZ, that call wouldn't work since FG% is a continuous variable and you set `family="binomial"`. Michael, it seems to me that the player's name needs to be included somehow since, for example, if a person is `80%` for `home` and `behind` then this information is relevant to estimating their percentage for, e.g. `away` and `behind`. In other words, multiple measurements on individuals are likely to be correlated so even if you want to look at the average effect (which you seem to suggest), you'd still need to account for the dependence for valid $p$-values using e.g. robust SEs from a GEE.

Comment: @Macro That's a good point.  But I don't think a random intercept can help with that either and we need somehow to get away from the 200 individual players.  What would you suggest?

Comment: I think I've got something working, but let me know what you think. First, for now, I'm going to ignore the two categorical factors, and just focus on players and FG% (pooling all shots together). If I run a logistic regression, it just gives me the MLE for each player, which I don't like. However, a call to lmer seems to do the trick. lmer(cbind(round(mean_efg*shots),shots)~(1|PLAYER),family=binomial(),data=a). When I run this, Rasual Butler is shrunk down to 47.1% and the top 3 are Jason Terry (48.2%), Ray Allen (47.86%), and Steve Nash (47.39%). Butler comes in 4th. This makes sense now.

Comment: As another example, Rodney Stuckey gets regressed up from 25% (on 110 shots) to 41%, while Russell Westbrook (647 shots), goes from 35% to 39.92% (and occupies last place).